# Error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE', checkbox list to filter Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, filter

I want to filter a grid view with checkbox list items, but I receive following error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>MT</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>AT</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Behind code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["carConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string strQuery = "SELECT Namecar, Images,GB,Tip as finalresult FROM Cdetail3 WHERE (Ghe BETWEEN @Start AND @End) order by finalresult DESC";
            string condition = string.Empty;
            foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                condition += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : string.Empty;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
            {
                condition = string.Format(" WHERE GB IN ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
            }
```

I guess it is because, where of check list put after order by , but how it can be fixed !

thanks for your help

Comment: what is the value for `@Start AND @End` and what is `condition`

Comment: they are INT (digit), and condition return length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "AND" to merge your two WHERE, following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql

Please remove WHERE from strQuery as follow:

```
string strQuery = "SELECT Namecar, Images,GB,Tip as finalresult FROM Cdetail3
```

and put it into condition:

```
condition = string.Format(" WHERE GB IN({0}) AND (Ghe BETWEEN @Start AND @End) order by finalresult DESC", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user enters in this if...

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
{
     condition = string.Format(" WHERE GB IN ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
}
```

... there will be two 'WHERE's in the query, which raises an error.

You could start by separating the "select" part of the query and the "where" part like

```
string strQuery = "SELECT Namecar, Images,GB,Tip as finalresult FROM Cdetail3"
string condition = "WHERE ..."
```

Apply logic to that condition string, and then merge together strQuery and condition